# XML Wrapper File for PDF Output?

Tags: javascript, c++, xml, xslt, pdf-generation

Fellow Forum Members,
I have the task of outputting a PDF which is sourced from several hundred XML files. Has anyone out there seen example XML code for what I am calling a wrapper file? Which can be described as a XML files that contains a list of all source XML file names by reference and organized in the order one needs them in for PDF output.  Am I correct in thinking that such a XML wrapper file can be coded in XML and then fed to a XSLT processor for PDF output?  OR does it require using JavaScript, or C++? My thinking is it might be possible to list all XML files within the XML wrapper file as references that will fetch the data from the XML source file and then feed it to the XSLT processor in a batch operation.  Is my thinking correct? Can anyone please post XML code that will accomplish such a task?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't figure out what your question is. Could you put it in the form of "this is my input" and "this is the output I am looking for?" See also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

XSLT provides the `document` function to pull in data from various input documents, the structure of the meta document can be defined by you, if you have e.g. `files.xml` with

```
<files>
  <file name="file1.xml"/>
  <file name="file2.xml"/>
  <file name="file3.xml"/>
</files>
```

then within XSLT where above file is the main input you can use `document(/files/file/@name)/*` to pull in and process the root elements of all listed files. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#document for details.